# Tabulator validator for regular expression to not take any space

Tags: javascript, angular, tabulator

I have a table and need regular expression validator for one column where no blank space is allowed in addition to other validator such as required, unique. I tred this but my validator is failing for all values. I want more control here as well such as able to know which validator is failing so that can give an exact error message to user with cell value and issue.

```
 colHeadersLibInit: Tabulator.ColumnDefinition[] = [
    {
      title: '',
      formatter: this.deleteIcon,
      headerSort: false,
      hozAlign: 'center',
      width: 50,
      cellClick: (e: any, cell: any) => this.deleteRow(e, cell),
    },
    {
      title: 'Parameter',
      field: 'Parameter',
      editor: 'input',
      editable: true,
      validator: ['required', 'unique', 'regex:/^\S/']
    }
  ]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to know which validation failed you need to use the `Validation callbacks`, you can see more information [here](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.0/callbacks#validation). Please let me know if this help you so I can put this as a response. Thank you.

Comment: Did not worked. Used validator